# How to setup a makefile in eclipse (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a project in Eclipse and I want to use my own makefile.
I went to

> project -> properties -> C/C++ Build

and unchecked "Generate Makfiles Automatically". I have a makefile named `Makefile` in the project base dir which just contains:

```
all: 
    g++ *.cpp -o Simulator.exe
```

When I try to build, I get the following error:

> Build of configuration MinGW GCC for project CacheOptimization
>
> (Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)

How can I fix this and make eclipse compile my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have MINGW configured properly, and Eclipse can't run "make". This might be useful: [Setting up a compiler](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler)

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- install `MSys` package which includes `make` along with other useful tools (recommended),
- or look into your project's settings under `C/C++ Build` and change the build command from `make` to `mingw32-make`, which is distributed as a part of MinGW.